# Does iTunes WiFi sync communicate with the Internet?

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes, wifi, ipod

When I use WiFi sync using my wireless router, is the data transfer completely in local network OR does it happen over the internet to iCloud or another service? Will the bandwidth used be deducted by my service provider?

Comment: To be clear - are you asking if the iOS device can use cellular data to go to a cell tower then in from your ISP to sync to your PC instead of local WiFi where no internet is involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iPhone talks to the internet while connected to WiFi, then yes, it costs your home internet bandwidth.  If it talks to the internet outside of of WiFi range, it costs your mobile internet bandwidth.

Syncing your phone with iTunes does not use the internet, it only uses the local network.  If your phone is configured to sync with iCloud, then it is using the internet.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: Downvote is probably because the question is specifically about iTunes Wifi Connect feature, not just network traffic. I believe iTunes Wifi Connect is about your Mac & iPad syncing data locally over the wifi without going through iCloud at all. But I'm not sure. But that seems to be what the Question is asking, which is my own question as well. I suspect you are answering a different question altogether.